# What are keyboard shortcuts to find next and previous error in Netbeans 8.2 editor?

Tags: netbeans, compiler-errors, keymapping, keymaps

***EDITED*** (see bottom)

Is there really, after so many years of unanswered questions such as mine, no keyboard shortcut to jump to the next or the previous error in Netbears 8.2?

[This page](https://shortcutworld.com/NetBeans/win/NetBeans_8_Shortcuts#General_Keyboard_Shortcts) says that the shortcuts are

```
Ctrl+./,    Next/previous usage/compile error
```

Note the inclusion of the word *usage*. In no other "Next/Previous" shortcut is *usage* used. I wonder why it's here and if it points to the problem. It's not exactly a typo. What might it mean? Yeah, probably nothing.

Whatever, absolutely nothing that I have found shows how to accomplish this very important pair of tasks.

Using `Tools > Options > Keymap` shows that `Ctrl+PERIOD` and `Ctrl+COMMA` are how to do it. But it doesn't work.

Once `Ctrl+PERIOD` took me SOMEwhere, and doing it again took me to the next occurrence of it, etc., but those lines of code had no errors and it doesn't happen now.

I've clicked on the ellipsis on the line for `Next Error` and `Previous Error` and edited them to be `Ctrl+BACKQUOTE` and `Alt+BACKQUOTE` and I clicked on the ellipsis and defined `alternative shortcuts` to be `Ctrl+CLOSE_BRACKET` and `Alt+CLOSE_BRACKET` and I could NOT define `Next error in Editor` to ANYTHING.

[image]

NOTHING works.

So my question is WHY NOT? I use F2 and shift+F2 in Android Studio with every error I get! How can this NOT be possible in Netbeans 8.2?

I am reluctant to upgrade to Netbeans 11 for just this, especially not knowing if this problem persists.

======================

***EDIT***

[image]

After looking at what @Dmitry_M submitted, I took another whack at it with the above definitions, which cause:

- `Alt+1` to take me to `Next Error`, but ONLY after a fresh `Build` or `Clean and Build Project`, and it takes me to other lines (in xml, for one) that have no errors (that I know of; they're not flagged).
- `Alt+2` to take me to `Previous Error` unless I fixed it, in which case it takes me to that same line that HAD the previous error, just as `Alt+1`takes me to where the next errors USED to be and to the other places, too.
- `Next Error in Editor` to do nothing.

This makes me wonder what `Category` actually means since `Next Error in Editor` says `Source` while the others that DO work say `System`.

My source files have more than a few "yellow warning" indicators, but unike Dmitry, the definitions don't find them.

If it finds the errors among other things, that's better than it was. But it only finds errors already listed in `Output`, and it requires build, and it finds other extraneous "errors". So I'll just look at `Output`. `Keymap` fails.

I'm discouraged with Netbeans 8.2.

Answer (score 1):

I am using NetBeans 8.1

### Next Error in Editor

The keymap moves a cursor to any hint or error that the editor shows. They are sometimes not compiler's errors. See it in action.

[image]

For example, the cursor moves to `int i = 0;` but there is no error there. There is just a hint that variable **i** is not used anywhere. And in the import statement: it's just a hint. 
If you want to define a keymap for `Next Error in Editor` action try different key combinations. I use alt+1.

### Previous Error/Next Error

The keymap only works for `clean and build` or `build` actions.

Probably, when just editing and saving NetBeans doesn't refresh errors list somewhere in the cache. It explains the behavior you experience: the cursor moves to a line where there are no errors. It simply moves to the line where an error was during the last build or clean and build action. 
Se it in action just after `clean and build`. It works:

[image]

The cursor indeed moves only between "real" compilers' errors. But it only works after clean and build or build action. Probably it's a bug. There is a relevant [bug](https://bz.apache.org/netbeans/show_bug.cgi?id=271546) but it was not resolved.

Also, in my case, `Ctrl+PERIOD` and `Ctrl+COMMA` were not working completely.  Changed my keymaps to this one:

[image]